# Is it possible to create a plain text file in android?

Tags: text-editor

I see lots of apps that can create "files that contain text", but the files are in their own proprietary format.
I would like to create a plain text file so that if the file is transferred to a computer, it could be opened using a common text editor, like notepad or gedit etc.
Is this possible?

device

- Samsung galaxy note 2
- running android 4.4.2

Comment: The question is equivalent to: What is a useful text editor for Android? Unfortunately it' hard to find a good one. I thought a found one, but it won't open "large" files like 3MB, even when I have 4GB RAM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install a third-party app to create a text file. There is a swarm of text editors in Google's proprietary [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=text%20editor&c=apps) app store and on free/libre and open source [F-Droid](https://search.f-droid.org/?q=text%20editor&lang=en) app store. Choose whichever text editor suits your needs.

Do note that some file manager apps also allow creating a plain text file, so check your file manager first to see if it provides such a feature or not.

You can also create a text file in your phone by connecting your phone to your PC in MTP (file transfer) mode and using your text editor in PC to save the text file in the phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you're serious about wanting to deal with plaintext on Android, I recommend installing Termux and learning how to use the Nano text editor (via Termux). Here are some links to help you get started there. Also, I recommend getting a bluetooth keyboard.

- https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux/ (download Termux; it's also on Google Play, but the latest version is here; scroll and click the link that says 'Download apk'--not the big button that says 'DOWNLOAD F-DROID', unless you want to install F-Droid and download it through there, which is said to be more secure; if you've never installed an .apk file before, you'll probably need to change an Android setting that lets you do it)
- https://www.growspice.com/Termux-tricks-td3491.html (some basic shortcuts that are useful when using Termux, to help you multitask and such)
- https://www.growspice.com/A-desktop-user-s-guide-to-Nano-a-command-line-text-editor-td3471.html (How to use the nano text editor.)

Okay, so once you have Termux installed, you basically have a Linux command-line app; no GUI, but you don't really need one terribly. You can install and use all sorts of programs that make your tablet useful--and you can make your own, if you're a programmer. As an added bonus, both Termux and Nano make it easy to multi-task once you learn how (in Termux ctrl+alt+c makes a new terminal; ctrl+alt+up/down moves between them; in Nano, you can move between open text files with alt+left/right).

So, in Linux, to create a text file, you can do it plenty of ways:

1. `touch myFile.txt` (that will create it if it's not there)
2. Type `nano myFile.txt` edit it, and save it.

Stuff like that. Learning how to use the Linux command-line will be important if you take this approach. You'll want to know commands like this:

- `ls` to show the contents of the current working directory
- `cd myDirectory` to change the directory to myDirectory
- Follow just about any command with `--help` (e.g. `nano --help`) to learn more about how to use it. `man whatEverMyCommandIs` also helps (it opens the manpage for it, if available).
- `rm myfile` to delete a file
- `rm -r myDirectory` to delete a directory/folder
- `mkdir myDirectory` to make a new directory
- `chmod +x myFile` to make a file executable
- `./myExecutableFile` to run an executable file that is in the current directory.
- `exit` to exit the shell (note you can type `bash` to create a new one running inside of the current one, so if you exit, you'll return to the old one)
- `pkg install myApp` to install a program called myApp (if it exists in the package manager); I don't remember if Nano comes pre-installed; if it doesn't, type `pkg install nano`.
- ctrl+c and ctrl+z are useful if you need to force quit a running program.
- Press tab to autocomplete stuff you're typing (like file and directory names).
- If you can't find a program for your purpose, see if someone has made one with Python; Python works on Termux, and so does pip (so, you've got access to lots of stuff).

There are more Termux-related apps on F-Droid, if you want to be able to do even more stuff with that.

Answer (score 0):

[Turbo Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maskyn.fileeditor) is what you're looking for.